# Lock level on MERGE statement

Tags: postgresql, sql-merge

Does anyone know what is the lock level (row, table) on PostgreSQL [MERGE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html) command? I tried to dig deep on the documentation but I couldn't find anything that could clarify my mind. If anyone have a clue and would be kind to share, that would be very appreciated.

Comment: See [Explicit Locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) and search for `MERGE`.

Comment: If you need to worry, then maybe `insert on conflict` is the better alternative. Unless the new MERGE command (of the not yet released version 15) gives you a feature that `insert on conflict` doesn't give you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES):

> ROW EXCLUSIVE Conflicts with the SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE,
> EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes.
>
> The commands UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT, and **MERGE** acquire this lock mode
> on the target table (in addition to ACCESS SHARE locks on any other
> referenced tables). In general, this lock mode will be acquired by any
> command that modifies data in a table.